# How to push json data into an arrya object in MONGO DB by java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
 "termsrelation" : [ 
      {
        "rel": "RT",
        "terms": [
            {
                "objid": "55dc25083d2cbcb8b0dc48c8",
                "source": null,
                "scopeNote": [
                    {
                        "sourceType": "source",                    
                        "source": "abc"
                    }
                ],
                "formated_name": "Milkbuns",
                "name": "Milkbuns",
                "type": null,
                "url": "test.com",
                "nodeid": "14050"
            },
            {
                "objid": "552cae1940feb9123e3f5fb6",
                "source": null,
                "scopeNote": [
                    {
                        "sourceType": "source",                    
                        "source": "xyz"
                    }
                ],
                "formated_name": "Milkchocolate",
                "name": "Milkchocolate",
                "type": null,
                "url": "test.com",
                "nodeid": "193570"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to push

```
{
                            "sourceType" : "source",                            
                            "source" : "def"
                        }
```

json to scopeNote object where name = Milkchocolate   by java, Please help me out

I tried this query `{ "$push" : { "termsrelation.$.terms.$.scopeNote" : { "sourceType" : "source" , "source" : "ddd" }}}` with search query `{ "$and" : [ { "id" : "4003"} , { "termsrelation.rel" : "RT"} , { "termsrelation.terms.scopeNote.sourceType" : "source"} , { "termsrelation.terms.scopeNote.source" : "xyz"} , { "termsrelation.terms.name" : "Milk chocolate"}]}` but didn't work

Comment: What have you tried? Please show a code attempt to give some context. It is very unclear whether `"termsrelation"` is the collection name or an element within a document.

Comment: It is an element with in a document

Comment: I tried this query { "$push" : { "termsrelation.$.terms.$.scopeNote" : { "sourceType" : "source" , "source" : "ddd" }}}  with search query { "$and" : [ { "id" : "4003"} , { "termsrelation.rel" : "RT"} , { "termsrelation.terms.scopeNote.sourceType" : "source"} , { "termsrelation.terms.scopeNote.source" : "xyz"} , { "termsrelation.terms.name" : "Milk chocolate"}]}
but didn't work

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33887489/edit) your question rather than posting in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. First get the position for element there which you want to insert

Step 2. You got the position

then use this query

```
List<BasicDBObject> andQuery2 = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
                andQuery2.add(new BasicDBObject("id", id));
                andQuery2.add(new BasicDBObject("termsrelation.rel", relation));
                andQuery2.add(new BasicDBObject("termsrelation.terms.name", name));

                BasicDBObject searchObj2 = new BasicDBObject();
                searchObj2.put("$and", andQuery2);

                BasicDBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject();
                basicDBObject.put("sourceType", type);
                basicDBObject.put("source", source);                


                BasicDBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject();
                updateQuery.append("$push", new BasicDBObject().append("termsrelation.$.terms."+position+".scopeNote", basicDBObject));


                coll.update(searchObj2, updateQuery).getError();
```